# How to expand a list column in scala to multiple rows

Tags: scala, databricks

I'd like to turn the following list:

```
val articledDF = spark.createDF(
  List(
    ("article 1", Array("topic 1", "topic 2")),
    ("article 2", Array("topic 1", "topic 3")),
    ("article 3", Array("topic 2"))
  ), List(
    ("article", StringType, true),
    ("topics", ArrayType(StringType, true), true)
  )
)
```

Which results in:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| name    |topics               |
+---------+---------------------+
|article 1|   [topic 1, topic 2]|
|article 2|   [topic 1, topic 3]|
|article 3|            [topic 2]|
+---------+---------------------+
```

And expand the column topics in the following way:

```
+---------+-----------+
| name    |topic      |
+---------+-----------+
|article 1|   topic 1 |
|article 1|   topic 2 |
|article 2|   topic 1 |
|article 2|   topic 3 |
|article 3|   topic 2 |
+---------+-----------+
```

Would be happy to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `explode`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

articledDF.select($"article", explode($"topics") as "topic")
```